# Llenar un SELECT a partir de dos SELECT con AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

necesito rellenar un select a partir de las opciones de dos select escogidos, sé que debo pasar las variables de ambos select al archivo ajax para que me retorne lo que necesito en el tercer select , pero no consigo hacerlo, les dejo el código del archivo del formulario y del archivo ajax, de antemano muchas gracias por su valiosa ayuda.

```
<select class="form-control form-control-user" id="carrera" name="carrera" required>
<option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>
<?php foreach($carreras as $c):?>
<option value="<?php echo $c->id_carrera; ?>"><?php echo $c->nombre_carrera;?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<select class="form-control form-control-user" id="semestre" name="semestre" required>
<option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>
<option value="1">Primer</option>
<option value="2">Segundo</option>
<option value="3">Tercer</option>
<option value="4">Cuarto</option>
<option value="5">Quinto</option>
<option value="6">Sexto</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control form-control-user" id="materia" name="materia" required>
<option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>
</select>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#carrera").change(function(){
            $.get("get_materias.php","carrera="+$("#carrera")+"&semestre="+semestre.val(), function(data){
                $("#materia").html(data);
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

get_materias.php

```
$query=$con->query("select * from materias where carrera=$_GET[carrera] AND semestre=$_GET[semestre]");
$materias = array();
while($r=$query->fetch_object()){ $materias[]=$r; }
if(count($materias)>0){
print "<option value=''>-- SELECCIONE --</option>";
foreach ($materias as $s) {
    print "<option value='$s->id_materia'>$s->nombre_materia</option>";
}
}else{
print "<option value=''>-- NO HAY DATOS --</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el `change` de carrera x el de semestre y sería bueno el semestre solo aparezca cuando la carrera este seleccionada asi ya le abligas a tener los dos valores

```
 <script language="javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ $("#semestre").change(function(){ 
            $.get("g2et_materias.php","carrera="+$("#carrera")+"&semestre="+semestre.val(), 
      function(data){ $("#materia").html(data); console.log(data); }); }); }); 
</script>
```